# how to make pexpect input into a function from another .py file

Tags: python, pexpect

```
import pexpect
from BODMASCalculator import math

Math = pexpect.spawn(math('aaaa'))
Math.expect("error incorrect Format try again?(y/n)")
Math.sendline('n')
```

Trying to get pexpect to input 'n' when it recieves this input from the math function
receiving this error when i try to run code

AttributeError: module 'pexpect' has no attribute 'spawn'

any help greatly appreciated